# Name based virtual host?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, httpd.conf

I have a new site that uses Apache2.  Looking at my server logs I see that there is a growing bunch of other domain names (all hosted with GoDaddy) that are mysteriously pointing to the IP address for my server.  I do not know that this does any harm but I cannot see any reason why I should allow the situation to persist.  From the bit of Googling I have done I have gathered that the way to stop this is to set up a name based virtual host and reject any attempts by other domain names to point to my content.  However, I am not at all sure how I set up the relevant entries.  Looking at commentary in my /etc/apache2/apache2.conf file I get the impression that I should do  something along the lines of

```
NameVirtualHost mysite.com:80
<VirtualHost mysite.com:80>
ServerName mysite.com
ServerAlias:www.mysite.com
ErrorLog:/var/log/mysite.error.log
CustomLog:/var/log/mysite.access.log
</VirtualHost>
```

This may or may not be right but I have never tinkered with apache configuration files in the wild and that apart it is not at all clear to me that this will stop anothercrappysite.com pointing to my IP address and displaying my content.

I'd be much obliged to anyone who might be able to tell me how I do things right here.

### p.s. - from what I can see I do not appear to have an httpd.conf file.  Just apache2.conf.

There is perhaps another way to do this by writing an htaccess rule that specifically redirects all requests that do not contain mysite.com or www.mysite.com to the default 404 page?

Comment: That looks more or less on track to me. To test, manually connect to your server (e.g. with "telnet") and simply send an HTTP request where you specify a "Host" header other than "mysite.com" or "www.mysite.com" and confirm that it gives a 404.

Comment: Thanks.  That did no harm but it does nothing at all to stop anothercrappysite.com showing my content.  I restarted apache and it reported no issues with my modified conf file.

Comment: Did you try the test procedure I suggested, though? Just because the config loads successfully doesn't mean it is doing what you expect. It's important after making these sorts of changes to actually test that they've been applied. Also, just for clarity, nothing prevents other websites (aside from the law) from violating your IP and displaying your content... doing this simply ensures your server only serves content accessed with the expected domains in the URL (but, for example, if you don't use X-Frame-Options, they could still <iframe> your page. And they could still just copy it).

Comment: Yes, I telnet'd as you suggest and also browsed to the site with the rogue domain name via Lynx on my server. No, there is nothing I can do to prevent other sites from pointing to my IP - I understand that. My concern is that I get look bad in the eyes of Google because those domains have spammy links.

Comment: Try putting the configuration that identifies the directories, files, etc. within the <VirtualHost></VirtualHost> and remove any of them from outside the <VirtualHost></VirtualHost> section. The allow/deny directives may also be of interest: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/access.html

Comment: Upvote for the suggestion re putting everything inside <VirtualHost>.  I found that the rewrite rule, see below, did nothing if outside <VirtualHost>...</VirtualHost>

Answer (score 0):

For the benefit of anyone who comes here in quest of a solution to a similar issue here is what to do

```
<VirtualHost ip_address:80>
ServerAdmin admin@...
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/
ServerName mysite.com
ServerAlias www.mysite.com
ErrorLog /var/log/mysite.error.log
CustomLog /var/log/mysite.access.log combined
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond  %{HTTP_HOST}  !^(www.mysite|mysite).com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ [F]
</VirtualHost>
```

It goes without saying that you should

- Put in the IP address of your server
- Use the domain name of your site
- Ensure that mod_rewrite is enabled

You can check to see what modules are enabled via a simple PHP script

```
<?php
print_r(apache_get_modules());
?>
```

If mod_rewrite does not figure in that list you can usually get it by simply copying it from

```
/etc/apache2/mods-available to
/etc/apache2/modes-enabled
```

and then restarting Apache

```
service apache2 restart
```